# Modify jQuery datatable search

Tags: jquery, search, datatable

I am using jQuery datatable in my application page. I want to modify search behavior.

Current behavior is as following: request sent to server on each search char when user enters search term(e.g. abc) in the text field.

Suppose if typed first type "a", then "b" and then "c" in the search field , for each char a request generated and send to the server  like

- www.myapplication.com/finddata&search=a
- www.myapplication.com/finddata&search=ab
- www.myapplication.com/finddata&search=abc

Each time table refreshed and data display for each search char. Table refresh sequence like this

1. first search result of "a" will display
2. then search result of "ab" will display
3. then search result og "abc" will display

This is absolutely fine when table has small amount of data. User couldn't notice quick data data change on the table, however user is only interested to see data for last search term.

The problem stated when table has thousands of rows and 30 or more columns (for example below image). Then table execution become slower and user easily notice table refresh for each search char, however user only interested in result of last search query. User shouldn't notice that result of first search query (char) then 2nd and third and so on..

[image]

Is it possible to modify that behavior in datatable? I can't see any configuration parameter for this or it is required to modify datatable library itself?

Comment: Just to confirm, you make the ajax call that you make to load the data, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a single AJAX request! 
Basically, every time user types in a character, `abort` the existing AJAX call and then start a new one.

**Psuedocode**

```
var request;
onkeyup = function(){
  if(request && request.readystate != 4){
     request.abort();
  }
  request = $.ajax(/* new request */);
}
```

Worth a shot!